# How can a Wix Burn MBA show .Net Framework installation Progress?

Tags: c#, .net, wix

My Wix/Burn bundle is installing .Net 4.6.1 on Windows 7, currently the .NET installer fires and shows its own UI window (two progress bars) over my Burn Setup Window.

Is there a way to suppress the .Net installer UI and pipe the messages to the Burn MBA installer UI?

My code:

```
<Bundle Name="A Test Application" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="TM" UpgradeCode="{26B5D0A5-96E9-477D-8FE1-1DA027D534F8}">    

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
      <Payload SourceFile="..\TestBA\BootstrapperCore.config"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\TestBA\bin\Release\TestBA.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\TestBA\bin\Release\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain DisableSystemRestore="yes">
      <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx461Full' />
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\DummyInstaller\bin\Release\DummyInstaller.msi" Id="DummyInstallationPackageId" Cache="yes" Visible="no"/>
    </Chain>

  </Bundle>

  <Fragment>
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx461Full" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />

    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" Value="CurrentVersion" Variable="WIN_Version" />

    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="var_Netfx4" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="var_Netfx4x64" Win64="yes" />

    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Release" Variable="var_Netfx4Release" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Release" Variable="var_Netfx4x64Release" Win64="yes" />

    <PackageGroup Id="Netfx461Full">
      <ExePackage Id="Net461" Name="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Setup" Cache="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
        Compressed="yes"  
        InstallCommand="/q"
        SourceFile="C:\Users\Martin\Documents\.Net Frameworks\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
        DetectCondition="(var_Netfx4x64 &lt;&lt; &quot;4.6&quot;) OR (var_Netfx4x64 &lt;&lt; &quot;4.6&quot;)"
        InstallCondition="(VersionNT &lt; v6.0 OR VersionNT64 &lt; v6.0) AND (NOT (var_Netfx4 OR var_Netfx4x64))" />
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

BootstrapperCore.Config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="wix.bootstrapper" type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperSectionGroup, BootstrapperCore">
      <section name="host" type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.HostSection, BootstrapperCore" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <!--<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />-->
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    <!--<supportedRuntime version="v4.6"/>-->
  </startup>
  <wix.bootstrapper>
    <host assemblyName="TestBA">
      <!--<supportedFramework version="v4.6" />-->
      <supportedFramework version="v4\Full" />
      <supportedFramework version="v4\Client" />
      <!--<supportedFramework version="v3.5" />-->
    </host>
  </wix.bootstrapper>
</configuration>
```

My intention is to have one user window experience which installs the .Net 4.6.1 (if required) and then my application, with one progress bar and informative status messages

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's offline installer? Probably you are using online installer.
This is the right one:
https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=49982

My example of ExePackage working in one window:

```
<ExePackage Id="NetFx46Redist" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1" Compressed="$(var.IsCompressed)" Cache="yes"
                        bal:PrereqSupportPackage="yes"
                        PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Protocol="netfx4" Vital="yes" SourceFile="$(var.PRMSourceDir)NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
                        InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot[WixBundleName]&quot;" RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
                        UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
                        DetectCondition="(WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED=1)" />
```

Don't use this DetectCondition, will not work.

Btw, something is completely wrong with your detect condition. 
Check the instruction:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx